# SHA1CryptoServiceProvider in .NET doesn't match UNIX shasum

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, sha1

I'm trying to share authentication between an ASP.NET app and another UNIX-based app, where the hashed password is stored in the database. I need to ensure the hashing algorithms on both platforms match.

This is how I'm hashing in C#:

```
var sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
var passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
var passwordHash = sha1.ComputeHash(passwordBytes);
var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(passwordHash);
return base64;
```

If I use the password `p@ssw0rd` the hash is `57B2AD99044D337197C0C39FD3823568FF81E48A` and the base64 of that hash is `V7KtmQRNM3GXwMOf04I1aP+B5Io=`. The base64 hash is what is stored in the db.

If I do the same thing on UNIX, I get a totally different hash:

`echo p@ssw0rd | iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 | shasum -a 1 | base64 -e`
produces
`ZTU3NmQwNmUzMTAwNmRkNzFhNTFjZTg5ZjViMGI4NWM2NTMyNzg3OCAgLQo=`

If you try it with OpenSSL, use this `echo "p@ssw0rd" |  openssl dgst -sha1 | openssl enc -base64` and you will get the same hash.

What is different about the two SHA1 algorithms that causes different hashes to be computed? I'm not salting these either.

**UPDATE**

The secret sauce is as follows:
`echo -n "p@ssw0rd" | openssl dgst -sha1 -binary | openssl enc -base64`

`echo -n` strips the newline, and `-binary` is essential.

Hope this can help someone.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: One thing I notice is that the hash produced by SHA1CryptoServiceProvider is 20 bytes (which is correct for SHA 1, I gather), but the hash produced by the UNIX command is 44 bytes.

Comment: That's because `shasum` converts the hash to hex before it outputs it.

Comment: Daniel, I also noticed the hash size discrepancy. I am looking at OpenSSL to see if it can be tweaked to produce a 160 bit hash.

Answer (score 5):

- echo adds a newline, you need to do `echo -n`
- shasum might do the same, check the output of that before you pipe it to base64)
- sha1.ComputeHash() gives you back binary hash representation ,not the hexadecimal representation as the shasum utility produces - which means you're base64 encoding different things in C# vs the unix command line. Use e.g. `var passwordHashHex = String.Concat(Array.ConvertAll(passwordHash , x => x.ToString("X2"));` to convert to hex before you do the base64 conversion in C#

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual:

> The sums are computed as described in
>   FIPS PUB 180-2.  **When checking, the
>   input should be a former output of
>   this program.**  The default mode is to
>   print a line with checksum, a
>   character indicating type ('*' for
>   binary, '?' for portable, ' ' for
>   text), and name for each FILE.

It's probably (I don't know) generating a salted hash.  It's not of a length consistent with just a hash value alone.

Have you tried using "**sha1sum**" instead?  I get conflicting information on this one, but it might work.